# On converting the UFT-8 xml to Unicode in Powershell, $encoding attribute value is showing bigEndianUnicode in the output xml, I want UTF-16 there

Tags: xml, powershell, unicode, encoding, utf-8

Getting this line in output file after converting UTF-8 to Unicode

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="bigEndianUnicode"?>
```

But I need below line in the xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're working with [`[xml]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=netframework-4.8) type, you can set encoding of a XML file as follows:

```
[xml] $xmlData = '<example>XML</example>'

$fileName = 'C:\test.xml'

$settings = New-Object System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings

# Set encoding to UTF-16
$settings.Encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode

$xmlWriter = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create($fileName, $settings)

$xmlData.Save($xmlWriter)

$xmlWriter.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

[Giorgi Chakhidze's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70452889/45375) shows a proper, XML *API*-based way to produce an XML file with a given encoding that is also reflected in the output file's XML declaration.

However, it sounds like you've used *plain-text* processing to *transcode* files from UTF-8 to "Unicode" (UTF-16LE), and must now adapt these files' XML declarations to match the new encoding.

The following shows a solution for a single `file.xml` file (it assumes that `file.xml` has a "Unicode" (UTF-16LE) *BOM*, so that [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) interprets its encoding correctly):

```
(Get-Content -Raw -LiteralPath file.xml) -replace '(?<=^.+ encoding=")[^"]+', 'utf-16' |
  Set-Content -NoNewLine -Encoding Unicode -LiteralPath file.xml
```

However, it's unclear how your transcoded-from-UTF-8 files ever ended up with `encoding="bigEndianUnicode"` in their XML declaration.